# шаблон отрисовки даных в datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Добрый день!

есть класс с данными:

```
class testClass{

    public string  field1 {get set}
    public string  field2 {get set}
    public int     field3 {get set}
}
```

делаю его источником данных для грида:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = new BindingList<MyTestClass>;
```

Вопрос:
Возможно ли настроить шаблон отрисовки строк/ячеек в гриде?

К примеру строка меняет цвет на красный, если `field3 >5`

Comment: Надо бы тег добавить, который уточнит технологию: `WinForms` или `WPF`. В случае `WPF` для изменения цвета в зависимости от значения данных можно воспользоваться `DataTemplate`.

Comment: извиняюсь, добавил  тег winforms. В WPF я делаю через задание стиля ячейки с использованием конвертеров.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то типа этого:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView.Rows) 
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value) < 5) 
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; 
    }
}
```